# how to create array of instances?

Tags: iphone, ios, nsarray, afnetworking

I have class Friend

```
#import "Friend.h"
#import "AFJSONRequestOperation.h"
#import "UIImageView+AFNetworking.h"
#import "AFHTTPClient.h"

@implementation Friend

-(id)init {
    self = [super init];
    return self;
}

-(id)initWithSecret:(NSString *)theSecret
         userId:(NSString *)theUserId {
self = [super init];
if(self) {
    secret = theSecret;
    user_id = theUserId;
    /// get friends
    NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.vk.com/method/friends.get?fields=first_name,last_name&uid=%@&access_token=%@", user_id, secret];
    NSURL *url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:str];
    NSURLRequest *friendRequest = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];

    AFJSONRequestOperation *friendOperation = [AFJSONRequestOperation JSONRequestOperationWithRequest:friendRequest success:^(NSURLRequest *friendRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, id JSON) {
        //converting to array
        NSArray *ar = [JSON valueForKey:@"response"];

        NSData *jsonAr = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:ar options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
        friendsAr = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonAr options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil ];

        self.firstName = [friendsAr valueForKey:@"first_name"];
        self.lastName = [friendsAr valueForKey:@"last_name"];
        self.uid = [friendsAr valueForKey:@"uid"];

    } failure:^(NSURLRequest *friendRequest, NSHTTPURLResponse *response, NSError *error, id JSON) {
        NSLog(@"Request Failed with Error: %@, %@", error, error.userInfo);
    }];

    [friendOperation start];

}
return self;
}


@end
```

In my ViewController I can create an instance like that:

```
 self.myFriend = [[Friend alloc] initWithSecret:self.secret userId:self.user_id];
```

It works fine, but when I try to create an array:

```
NSMutableArray *persons = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (int i = 0; i < 165; i++) {
        self.myFriend = [[Friend alloc] initWithSecret:self.secret userId:self.user_id];
        [persons addObject: self.myFriend];
    }
    self.arrayOfPersons = [NSArray arrayWithArray:persons];
```

it crashes with the error: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** +[NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:]: value parameter is nil' ". Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: BTW - your question title has nothing at all to do with the problem.

Comment: Then why it works fine when I create one instance? I don't have this error.

Comment: Use the debugger and figure out what's different.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is pretty clear. In your call to `NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:options:error:` you are passing `nil` to the first parameter.

You have:

```
NSData *jsonAr = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:ar options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];
```

This means that `ar` is `nil`.

Since you get `ar` as follows:

```
NSArray *ar = [JSON valueForKey:@"response"];
```

This means either `JSON` (whatever that is) is `nil` or it has no value for a `response` property.

Simple use of the debugger and looking at values as you step through the offending code would have told you all of this.